# SABRE: Concierge 5.10.1 Errors with ngv run?

Tags: sabre

Has anyone installed the latest concierge with the RedWeb SDK?
Since installing I can no longer save and have the program automatically compile the code. It will compile and then loops. Normally you save your file and it automatically compiles and responds with the ready and the localhost, etc... I have to kill the terminal session in VSC and restart a terminal session and do ngv run and it will work.
Note: This is the Concierge version released this week. We are developing specifically for RedWeb and not the desktop version which has a different SDK. Just curious if anyone is experience this with SabreRedWeb-SDK-21.5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues with that version also. Sabre has just finalized version 21.6 SDK and it should be on the website soon. The newer version worked fine with all my testing so far.

Comment: I've also found in the 21.6 SDK with that version of concierge  I have to run Visual Studio Code in Admin mode for it to handle the ngv run.